# What is the smallest integer $s$ such that $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x \cos (n x)}{n^s+1} $ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: calculus

> What is the smallest integer $s$ such that $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x \cos (n x)}{n^s+1} $ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$?

So far I know this means

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{d}{dx} \frac{x \cos (n x)}{n^s+1} $$

converges uniformly over $\mathbb{R}$, but what to do next?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how do you prove the former "means" the latter, i.e. both are *equivalent*? + include some work https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask (otherwise your post should be soon closed without hint or answer).

Comment: I suspect that the smallest positive integer $s$ for which your series will be differentiable is $3$, by using the Weierstrass M-test. See [this example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109616/prove-fx-sum-n-1-infty-frac-sin-nx-cos-nx-n3-is-a-different?rq=1).